# Multiple columns sorting with additional logic in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Sometimes in my result set I have items that have the same _score and that's ok but I would like to pull up the documents for which start_date and end_date are between "now" within the same _score.

Basically I want to accomplish an equivalent of this but in ElasticSearch:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ... ORDER BY _score DESC, (start_date <= NOW() AND NOW() <= end_date) DESC
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about integrating that `(start_date <= NOW() AND NOW() <= end_date)` comparison inside the query score calculation itself?

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        // your query here
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "start_date": {
                    "lte": "2015-03-03"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "end_date": {
                    "gte": "2015-03-03"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Or, there is also the possibility of using scripts:

```
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "def now_date=new DateTime(new Date()); if (doc['start_date'].date <= now_date && doc['end_date'].date >= now_date) return 1; return 0",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```